# Why does rotate option not rotate all objects (except labels) of my pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I've a `pic` including a spacecraft and a local frame attached to it as below.

```
pics/spacecraft/.style n args={2}{
        code={
            \node [shape=rectangle, draw, fill=gray!30, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.9em, minimum height=0.9em] () {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=2mm, rotate around={90:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=2mm, rotate around={180:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=-2mm, rotate around={0:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=-2mm, rotate around={270:(0,0)}] {};
            \draw (0,0) circle (0.7mm);
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (0:0.7mm) arc(0:90:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (180:0.7mm) arc(180:270:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[-latex, very thin] (0,0) -- (0,9mm) node[pos=0.9,above] {$\Scale[#2]{y_{#1}}$};
            \draw[-latex, very thin, label=right:2mm] (0,0) -- (9mm,0) node[pos=0.9,right] {$\Scale[#2]{x_{#1}}$};
        }
    }
```

I'd like to rotate the whole pic (except its labels) using `[rotate = <some degree>]`. But current code only rotates the frame not the spacecraft.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,,shapes.geometric,arrows.meta}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathpazo}


\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%

\tikzset{
    pics/spacecraft/.style n args={2}{
        code={
            \node [shape=rectangle, draw, fill=gray!30, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.9em, minimum height=0.9em] () {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=2mm, rotate around={90:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=2mm, rotate around={180:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=-2mm, rotate around={0:(0,0)}] {};
            \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=-2mm, rotate around={270:(0,0)}] {};
            \draw (0,0) circle (0.7mm);
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (0:0.7mm) arc(0:90:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (180:0.7mm) arc(180:270:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[-latex, very thin] (0,0) -- (0,9mm) node[pos=0.9,above] {$\Scale[#2]{y_{#1}}$};
            \draw[-latex, very thin, label=right:2mm] (0,0) -- (9mm,0) node[pos=0.9,right] {$\Scale[#2]{x_{#1}}$};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[rotate=120] (scB) at (3.5,1.5) {spacecraft={1}{0.5}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes only transform if the `transform shape` option is set:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,shapes.geometric,arrows.meta}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%

\tikzset{
    pics/spacecraft/.style n args={2}{
        code={
            \begin{scope}[
                every node/.style = {
                    transform shape
                }
            ]
                \node [shape=rectangle, draw, fill=gray!30, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.9em, minimum height=0.9em] () {};
                \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=2mm, rotate around={90:(0,0)}] {};
                \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=2mm, rotate around={180:(0,0)}] {};
                \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, yshift=-2mm, rotate around={0:(0,0)}] {};
                \node [trapezium, fill=gray!30, trapezium angle=60, inner sep = 1pt, minimum width=1mm, draw, xshift=-2mm, rotate around={270:(0,0)}] {};
            \end{scope}
            \draw (0,0) circle (0.7mm);
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (0:0.7mm) arc(0:90:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) --  (180:0.7mm) arc(180:270:0.7mm) -- cycle;
            \draw[-latex, very thin] (0,0) -- (0,9mm) node[pos=0.9,above] {$\Scale[#2]{y_{#1}}$};
            \draw[-latex, very thin, label=right:2mm] (0,0) -- (9mm,0) node[pos=0.9,right] {$\Scale[#2]{x_{#1}}$};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[rotate=120] (scB) at (3.5,1.5) {spacecraft={1}{0.5}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Roboticist Updated!